# How to extract local video stream (camera) in quickblox Android?

Tags: android, quickblox

How to capture particular frame in local video view(from local camera) while on video chat and convert into a bitmap in quickblox android sdk 2.5.1?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: No. Local Video View(RTCGLVideoView extends GLSurfaceView) has been rendering by quickblox sdk library class(VideoRendererGui extends Renderer) So I don't know how to get the frame from onDrawFrame in that class.

Comment: In video chat I have one button,Once user click the button I have to get the picture from camera(local video view). Camera is already in use so can't able to take picture without preview.